# Operator overloading for Int type class

Tags: c++, class, int, operator-overloading

I am writing a simple Int class and using operator overloading to enable the objects to behave in similar way to that of "int". I have broken my whole program into 3 files ,1) Header File : contains Class declaration 2) Definition of all operator overloaded functions 3) Test file containing main
These three are mentioned here in the same order

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Int
{
private:
    int i;
public:
    Int(): i(0) { }
    Int(int in) : i(in) { }
    void show() const
    {
        cout<<"value: "<<i<<endl;
    }
    Int operator +(const Int&) const;
    Int operator -(const Int&) const;
    Int operator *(const Int&) const;
    Int operator /(const Int&) const;
    //Int add(const Int&) const; 
};
```

Function definition

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>
#include <cassert>
#include "int.h"
using namespace std;
typedef unsigned long long ull;

Int Int::operator +(const Int &i1) const
{

    ull result;
    result = i+ i1.i;
    //cout<< result<<'\n';
    if (result>INT_MAX)
    {
        cout<<"Out of int range.\n";
        //assert(0);
    }
    else
        return Int(int(result));
}

Int Int::operator -(const Int &i1) const
{
    //typedef unsigned long long ull;
    ull result;
    result = i - i1.i;
    //cout<< result<<'\n';
    if (result < INT_MIN)
    {
        cout<<"Out of int range.\n";
        //assert(0);
    }
    else
        return Int(int(result));
}

Int Int::operator *(const Int &i1) const
{
    //typedef unsigned long long ull;
    ull result;
    result = i* i1.i;
    //cout<< result<<'\n';
    if (result >INT_MAX)
    {
        cout<<"Out of int range.\n";
        //assert(0);
    }
    else
        return Int(int(result));
}

Int Int::operator /(const Int &i1) const
{
    //typedef unsigned long long ull;
    ull result;
    result = i/ i1.i;
    //cout<< result<<'\n';
    if (result < INT_MIN)
    {
        cout<<"Out of int range.\n";
        //assert(0);
    }
    else
        return Int(int(result));
}
```

And test program with main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "int.h"

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Int i1;
    Int i2(4);Int i3(2);
    i1 = i2 + i3;
    i1.show();
    i1 = i2 - i3;
    i1.show();
    i1 = i2 * i3;
    i1.show();
    i1 = i2 / i3;
    i1.show();
    return 0;
}
```

Expected output is :

```
Value : 6,
Value : 2,
value : 8
Value : 2.
```

However I am getting the output like this :

```
value: 6
Out of int range.
value: 6
value: 8
Out of int range.
value: 8
```

I tried a lot where I am going wrong but unable to find.
Any lead will be great help.

Comment: Btw., if you want your class to be like `int` as much as possible, just with some additional methods, don´t start making + - etc. but make an (non-explicit) cast operator for `int` (in addition to your already existing constructor for the other direction)

Comment: @vik14dec It might look from first glance that member operators (`Int::operator + (const Int&)`) is easier to implement than standalone version (`friend Int operator + (const Int&, const Int&)`) - I do strongly advice to always prefer standalone versions whenever possible....

Comment: You should add a throw or a return inside those `if` branches btw

Comment: Daniel Jour, I used "assert(0)" for that . Just for checking output I commented that and pasted code here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is comparison of an unsigned value with a signed value:

```
if (result < INT_MIN)
```

More fundamentally, why did you want result to be `unsigned long long` when you want to act like a signed `int`?

I understand why you want to use a `long long` for range checking `int` operations (though doing so is not perfectly portable) but the choice of `unsigned` appears to be just a mistake.

Comment: This! Just use `int` instead of `ull` and you don't need all that casting

Answer (score 1):

Your `operator-` is causing the first Out-of-range.  In that operator, you have

```
    ull result;
```

and then

```
if (result < INT_MIN)
```

`INT_MIN` is an implementation-defined negative value, however `result` is unsigned and of type `unsigned long long`.  The *usual arithmetic conversions* (C++11 §5[expr]/9) dictate that in this case `INT_MIN` is converted to `unsigned long long`.  This is a "modulo" conversion, so it becomes a rather large positive integer, in any case much larger than the value `2` of result from your example.

Answer (score 0):

In the cases you print `cout<<"Out of int range.\n";` you don't return any value.

Also you should use `long` and `long long` as types. `int` may not be 32bit.
And using the `unsigned` types will produce wrong results (think about -1 * -1)

What you need is something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Int
{
private:
    long i;
public:
    Int() : i(0) { }
    Int(long in) : i(in) { }
    Int(const Int& other) :i(other.i) {}

    void show() const
    {
        cout << "value: " << i << endl;
    }


    Int& operator+=(const Int& other) 
    {
        long long result = i;
        result += other.i;
        if (result >= LONG_MIN && result <= LONG_MAX)
        {
            i = result;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Out of int range." << endl;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    Int operator-=(const Int& other) {
        long long result = i;
        result -= other.i;
        if (result >= LONG_MIN && result <= LONG_MAX)
        {
            i = result;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Out of int range." << endl;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    Int operator*=(const Int& other) 
    {
        long long result = i;
        result *= other.i;
        if (result >= LONG_MIN && result <= LONG_MAX)
        {
            i = result;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Out of int range." << endl;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    Int operator/=(const Int& other) 
    {
        long long result = i;
        result /= other.i;
        if (result >= LONG_MIN && result <= LONG_MAX)
        {
            i = result;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Out of int range." << endl;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    Int operator+(const Int& other) const
    {
        return Int(*this) += other;
    };

    Int operator-(const Int& other) const
    {
        return Int(*this) -= other;
    };

    Int operator*(const Int& other) const
    {
        return Int(*this) *= other;
    };

    Int operator/(const Int& other) const
    {
        return Int(*this) /= other;
    };
};
```

Comment: Thanks for these shorthand operators' code. Problem lies with my 'unsigned' variable.Fixed it and it is perfect now.

Comment: Not only. Try this one `(Int(INT_MAX) + Int(INT_MAX) + Int(INT_MAX)).show();`

You need to decide what to return in the "out-of-bounds" case.

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems with your code.

First, you compare an unsigned value (the result) with a signed constant (INT_MIN).

Secondly, if you comment out the 'assert' statement in the out-of-bounds check, you must still return a value from the function. Some compilers may warn you with something like this: "control reaches end of non-void function." This may not show right now, but when you start trapping errors, your program will most likely crash.